# What kind of resolution relation exists between ios x2 and x3 images resolution

Tags: ios

In iOS if I want to show 100x100 pixel image for in iphone6 for example (x2), how can calculate the size I\ll need for iphone 6 plus (x3)?

Comment: If 100 is 1x, 200 (100 * 2) is 2x, 300 (100 * 3) is 3x.

Comment: Write your note as answer to accept it becuase this answers my question